# Using implicit parameters in Agda

Tags: types, proof, agda

I am just starting out with Agda and have been following the [LearnYouAnAgda tutorial](http://williamdemeo.github.io/2014/02/27/learn-you-an-agda/#universal-quantification), in which I have been shown this proof for identity:

```
proof : (A : Set) → A → A
proof _ x = x
```

From what I understand the `_` is necessary to omit the parameter `(A : Set)`. I wanted to use an implicit parameter to allow me to omit the `_`:

```
-- using implicit parameter
proof' : {A : Set} → A → A
proof' x = x
```

This proof works. I then wanted to apply it to a specific case, as is done in the tutorial. I define `ℕ` and give the type signature for what I want to prove:

```
data ℕ : Set where
  zero : ℕ
  suc : ℕ → ℕ

idProof : ℕ → ℕ
```

The constructor given in the tutorial using `proof` is:

```
idProof = proof ℕ
```

I don't fully understand this, since I expected `proof` would need 2 parameters considering the constructor we have already defined.

I wanted to write a constructor using `proof'` but I found that none of the following worked:

```
idProof = proof' ℕ
idProof = {x : ℕ} → proof' x
idProof = {x : Set} → proof' x
```

Using the solver however I found this worked:

```
idProof = proof' (λ z → z)
```

My questions are:

1. What are the differences between `proof` and `proof'`?
2. Why is it acceptable to use a single parameter, `ℕ`, for `proof`?
3. Why do the three constructors using `proof'` not work?

Bonus:

A small explanation of how `idProof = proof' (λ z → z)` works (esp. the lambda) would be appreciated, unless it would likely be out of my current level of understanding of Agda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't fully understand this, since I expected `proof` would need 2 parameters considering the constructor we have already defined.

`proof` does expect 2 parameters. But `idProof` also expects one parameters.

When you write

```
idProof : ℕ → ℕ
idProof = proof ℕ
```

It's equivalent to first introducing `idProof`'s `ℕ` and then passing it to `proof ℕ` like so.

```
idProof : ℕ → ℕ
idProof n = proof ℕ n
```

> I wanted to write a constructor using proof' but I found that none of the following worked:

- `idProof = proof' ℕ`

The `A` parameter for `proof'` is implicit. So there is no need to pass `ℕ` explicitly. You can just write `idProof = proof'` and let Agda figure out that `A` should be `ℕ`.

- `idProof = {x : ℕ} → proof' x` and `idProof = {x : Set} → proof' x`

`idProof` is of type `ℕ → ℕ` but `{x : _} → ...` is used to construct a `Set`, not a function so it can't work.

> Bonus: A small explanation of how `idProof = proof' (λ z → z)` works (esp. the lambda)

`proof' : {A : Set} -> A -> A` tries to figure out what `A`should be based on its argument and the type of the hole it is used in. Here:

- it is passed an identity function so `A` should have the shape `B -> B` for some `B`;
- it used in a hole of type `ℕ → ℕ` so `A` should be of the shape `ℕ → ℕ`.

Conclusion: Agda picks `ℕ → ℕ` for `A`.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you really want to give an implicit argument explicitly, you can: `idProof = proof' {ℕ}`. This can be useful sometimes when Agda's solver doesn't manage to find the answer (i.e. you get yellow highlighting).